# Howto read service endpoint name from inside service implementation

Tags: .net, wcf

---

I am hosting several endpoints under same service host, which implement same service contract. I need to start different business layer based on the endpoint name, so is there a way I get endpoint name inside my service implementation constructor? Basically, as a service I need to know which endpoint I was started under.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out the `OperationContext.Current;` in your service code - it contains amongst other things an `EndpointDispatcher`:

```
 OperationContext ctx = OperationContext.Current;
 EndpointDispatcher epd = ctx.EndpointDispatcher;
```

That endpoint dispatcher has lots of properties such as ContractName, ContractNamespace, EndpointAddress and lots more.

Check the relevant MSDN documentation for [OperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx) and [EndpointDispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.endpointdispatcher.aspx) for the detailed list of properties they give you.